# DB Selection and Modeling Time Series Data with Ad-Hoc queries

Tags: time-series, data-modeling, rdbms, influxdb

I have to develop a system for tracking/monitoring performance in a cellular network.

The domain includes a set of hierarchical elements, and each one has an associated set of counters that are reported periodically (every 15 minutes). The system should collect these counter values (available as large XML files) and periodically aggregate them on two dimensions: ***Time*** (from 15 to hour and from hour to day) and ***Hierarchy*** (lower level to higher level elements). The aggregation is most often a simple SUM but sometime requires average/min/max etc. Of course for the element dimension aggregation it needs to group by the hierarchy (group all children to one parent record). The user should be able to define and view KPIs (Key Performance Indicator) - that is, some calculations on the various counters. The KPI could be required for just one element, for several elements (producing a data-series for each) or as an aggregation for several elements (resulting in one data series of aggregated data.

There will be about 10-15 users to the system with probably 20-30 queries an hour. The query response time should be a few seconds (up to 10-15 for very large reports including many elements and long time period).

In high level, this is the flow:

1. **Parse and Input Counter Data** - there is a set of XML files which contains a periodical update of counters data for the elements. The size of all files is about 4GB / 15 minutes (so roughly 400GB/day).
2. **Hourly Aggregation** - once an hour all the collected counters, for all the elements should be aggregated - every 4 records related to an element are aggregated into one hourly record which should be stored.
3. **Daily Aggregation** - once a day, 2 all collected counters, for all elements should be aggregated - every 24 records related to an element are aggregated into one daily record.
4. **Element Aggregation** - with each one of the time-dimension aggregation it is possibly required to aggregate along the hierarchy of the elements - all records of child elements are aggregated into one record for the parent element.
5. **KPI Definitions** - there should be some way for the user to define a KPI. The KPI is a definition of a calculation based on counters from the same granularity (Time dimension). The calculation could (and will) involved more than one element level (e.g. p1.counter1 + sum(c1.counter1) where p1 is a parent of one or more records in c1).
6. **User Interaction** - the user can select one or more elements and one or more counters/KPIs, the granularity to use, the time period to view and whether or not to aggregate the selected data.

   - In case of **aggregation**, the results is one data-series that include the "added up" values for all the selected elements for each relevant point in time. In "SQL":

     SELECT p1.time SUM(p1.counter1) / SUM(p1.counter2) * SUM(c1.counter1)
     FROM p1_hour p1, c1_hour c1
     WHERE p1.time > :minTime and p1.time < :maxTime AND p1.id in :id_list and join
     GROUP BY p1.time
   - In case there is **no aggregation** need to keep the identifiers from p1 and have a data-series for each selected element

     SELECT p1.time, p1.id, SUM(p1.counter1) / SUM(p1.counter2) * SUM(c1.counter1)
     FROM p1_hour p1, c1_hour c1
     WHERE p1.time > :minTime and p1.time < :maxTime AND p1.id in :id_list and join

The system has to keep data for 10, 100 and 1000 days for 15-min, hour and daily records. Following is a size estimate considering integer only columns at 4 bytes for storage with 400 counters for elements of type P, 50 for elements of type C and 400 for type GP:

[image: Sizes Estimate]

As it adds up, I assume the based on DDL (in reality, DBs optimize storage) to 3.5-4 TB of data plus probably about 20-30% extra which will be required for indexes. For the child "tables", can get close to 2 billion records per table.

It is worth noting that from time to time I would like to add counters (maybe every 2-3 month) as the network evolves.

I once implemented a very similar system (though probably with less data) using Oracle. This time around I may not use a commercial DB and must revert to open source solutions. Also with the increase popularity of no-SQL and dedicated time-series DBs, maybe relational is not the way to go?

How would you approach such development? What are the products that could be used?

From a few days of research, I came up with the following

- Use MySQL / PostGres
- InfluxDB (or a similar product)
- Cassandra + Spark
- Others?

How could each solution would be used and what would be the advantages/disadvantages for each approach? If you can, elaborate or suggest also the overall (hardware) architecture to support this kind of development.

Comments and suggestions are welcome - preferably from people with hands on experience with similar project.

Answer (score 0):

Going with Open Source RDBMS:

Using MySQL or Postgres

The table structure would be (imaginary SQL):

```
CREATE TABLE LEVEL_GRANULARITY (
    TIMESTAMP DATE,
    PARENT_ID INT,
    ELEMENT_ID INT,
    COUNTER_1 INT
    ...
    COUNTER_N INT
    PRIMARY_KEY (TIMESTAMP, PARENT_ID, ELEMENT_ID)
)
```

For example we will have P1_HOUR, GP_HOUR, P_DAY, GP_DAY etc.

The tables could be partitions by date to enhance query time and ease data management (can remove whole partitions).

To facilitate fast load, use loaders provided with the DB - these loaders are usually faster and insert data in bulks.

Aggregation could be done quite easily with `SELECT ... INTO ...' query (since the scope of the aggregation is limited, I don't think it will be a problem).

Queries are straight forward as aggregation, grouping and joining is built in. I am not sure about the query performance considering how large the tables are.

Since it is a write intensive I don't think the clustering could help here.

Pros:

- Simple configuration (assuming no clusters etc).
- SQL query capabilities - flexible

Cons:

- Query performance - will it work?
- Management overhead
- Rigid Schema
- Scaling?

Answer (score 0):

Using InfluxDB (or something like that):

***I have not used this DB and writing from playing around with it some***

The model would be to create a time-series for every element in every level and granularity.

The data series name will include the identifiers of the element and the granularity.

For example `P.P_ElementID.G.15MIN` or `P.P_ElementID.C.C1_ELEMENT_ID.G.60MIN`

The data series will contain all the counters relevant for that level.

The input has to parse the XML and build the data series name before inserting the new data points.

InfluxDB has an SQL like query language. and allows to specify the calculation in an SQL like manner. It also supports grouping. To group by element would be possible by using regular expression, e.g. `SELECT counter1/counter2 FROM /^P\.P_ElementID\.C1\..*G\.15MIN/` to get all children of ElementID.

There is a notion of grouping by time in general it is made for this kind of data.

Pros:

- Should be fast
- Support queries etc very similar to SQL
- Support Deleting by Date (but have to do it on every series...)
- Flexible Schema

Cons:
 * Currently, seems not to support clusters very easily (
 * Clusters = more maintenance
 * Can it support millions of data-series (and still work fast)
 * Less common, less documented (currently)